# ListView with ImageView - how to put different link to every ImageView in list

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, hyperlink

i'm working on my first project. I need an advice. My app should display user the exercises,when user will tap on a "play" Icon located on left side,app should move by intent to youtube to video which will show user how to do exercise properly. Here's some code.

Constructor

```
public class Constructor {

private String mExcersiseName;
private String mBodyPart;
private String mYoutubeLink;

public Constructor(String excersiseName, String bodyPart, String youtubeLink){
    mExcersiseName = excersiseName;
    mBodyPart = bodyPart;
    mYoutubeLink = youtubeLink;
}

public String getExcersiseName(){
    return mExcersiseName;
}
public String getBodyPart(){
    return mBodyPart;
}
public String getYoutubeLink(){return mYoutubeLink;}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Constructor>{
String mYoutubeLink;

public ExerciseAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Constructor> constructorList) {
    super(context, 0, constructorList);
    mYoutubeLink = youtubeLink;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if (listItem == null) {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_for_list, parent, false);

    }
    Constructor actualPosition = getItem(position);

    TextView exerciseName = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.list_excersise_name);
    exerciseName.setText(actualPosition.getExcersiseName());

    TextView bodyPart = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.list_body_part);
    bodyPart.setText(actualPosition.getBodyPart());

    return listItem;
}
}
```

Java class where we are putting data like exercise name, body part and link to youtube

```
public class BicepsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    ArrayList<Constructor> bicepsExercises = new ArrayList<Constructor>();
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));
    bicepsExercises.add(new Constructor("Lorem ipsum","Lorem","link"));

    ExerciseAdapter adapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this,bicepsExercises);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: You are going right, what's the problem?

Comment: When you will perform onItemclick opreation on litst view, then on the basis of list item position you can play your video .

Comment: your adapter is wrong. Where it says Constructor actualPosition... this is wrong. You need to have this.constructorList = constructorList. So add a list. This will take the list of objects that are passing into the adapter and make them global. So now you and do int potion = constructorList.getItem(position)